# Mutability and Spring

Tags: java, spring, immutability

I am currently re-reading "Effective Java" while working at a shop that makes heavy use of Spring Dependency Injection. When reading Bloch's book one cannot help but pick up on the emphasis he places on immutability in classes(he states several times that classes should be as immutable as possible). I can't help but feel this in direct conflict with the reliance that Spring Dependency Injection( and most DI engines for that fact) has on the javabeans standard. 
Reading 'Spring in Action' the chapters on DI seem like they would make Bloch cringe with their mutable classes composed of objects instantiated outside of your purview that could be mutable in their own right.

Is it that Bloch's ideas are too novel for Spring? Is the Spring model busted? Does Bloch's stance on immutability only apply to writing library code? When writing Spring code should I write flexible objects with lots of getters and setters or load everything up in the constructor?

Comment: Bloch doesn't say "never make things mutable" he says "don't make them any more mutable than necessary". If your framework necessitates a certainly level of mutability, then that's what you have to live with.

Comment: Well in the item regarding mutability, telescoping constructors, and the builder pattern he sort of trashes the javabeans standard(referring to it as out of date), but that standard is the basis of Spring does that mean spring is out of date?

Comment: spring has no reliance on the javabeans standard.

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=G4jk-NOpF7gC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=javabeans+standard+and+spring&source=bl&ots=PHoIhekKOc&sig=vGL0Zvt4WMaeVMPvx4fRUAMszs0&hl=en&ei=IPWuTaWWHcaw0QHMsPzGCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=javabeans%20standard%20and%20spring&f=false - sorry for the link. If you read this you can find a quote that says "Spring uses the JavaBeans specification to form the core of its DI configuration model". Page 4 3rd paragraph

Comment: I edited the post above. In all the places I put MVC I meant DI

Comment: You are absolutely right. You can use constructor injection what brings two problems: 1) ugly long constructor, 2) impossibility to use circular dependency. Solving those problems is actually pretty good. Enforce immutability would, in the end, enforce another good practices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In fact, spring beans are immutable by idea, even though you are not enforcing this.

You can provide only a getter to a `final` field that is initialized through constructor injection.

Usually you don't do so, but you are never supposed to reassign fields of beans that are injected by the DI framework. That's because spring beans usually do not hold any state, apart from their dependencies (and their scope is singleton). Of course, there are exceptions, like prototype and request scoped beans, that these are rare (for example in 2 big and 2 medium projects I've used only 1 prototype-scoped bean)

Comment: I agree : most Spring instanciated object are "singleton" and not really "mutable" (services, daos, controllers, transactionManagers, ...).

Comment: If I inject a mutable object into a final field that doesn't stop that object from changing resulting in a fragile object graph

Comment: @nsfyn55 it is entirely up to you what object to inject. It has nothing to do with DI.

Comment: Sure but what keeps me protected from mutability bugs such as injecting the same instance into a few classes, modifying some underlying member and corrupting the state of all the others that hold that instance. I know you're going to say "well don't do that" but there are a lot of shady programmers out there and Bloch seems to lean on things like defensive copying to mitigate these types of issues.

Comment: @nsfynn55: the objects in your app should only know about each other through their interfaces, unless they cast to the implementation there won't be any opportunity for them to mess with the setters. So if you have untrustworthy programmers, use tools like pmd to look out for casts, make sure setters are not part of interfaces, and build an integration test suite.

Comment: @nsfyn55 at the layer you are talking about, Spring has no role - the answer is all about how you design your code and interfaces.

Comment: Thats the problem you can't code an interface. I can create an interface with no setters, but it still implies trust that the instance injected isn't a promiscuos lady with her setters just hanging out there for the world to see. I feel like this represents some incompleteness in dependency injection and perhaps in the java language in general

Comment: @Nathan I can protect against casts but I can't protect against someone not using the interface. If I have a setterless interface Person and class PersonImpl with setters and my class Carnival has a setPerson(Person p) and their class CarnivalOfDeath has a setPerson(PersonImpl p) then if both those classes have the same instance your pooched if CarnivalOfDeath decides to modify PersonImpl

Comment: @nsfyn55 spring beans usually don't hold state, apart from their dependencies. And it's a rule of thumb not to change any dependencies. You can make them final to ensure that no incompetent developer can do any harm.

Comment: @Bozho - I don't think what you've said above is at all accurate. Spring Beans hold as much or as little state as you want them to. If you are following the recommended spring practice of having your property settings use an interface there is nothing that stops you from getting a reference to a mutable object and no way to know what other classes hold reference to that object.

Comment: for singleton beans you don't store state. And that's the majority of cases

Answer (score 10):

You can keep classes immutable and still use Dependency Injection if you use constructor-based injection. That way you can avoid unnecessary setters.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the conflict myself, especially with Spring MVC. Which beans are managed by Spring? Mostly your controllers and in your service/data layer your DAO's and services. These usually have no real state anyway and no setters as well. If your problem lies with the setter injection (for instance, your have your own class that needs to be managed by Spring and you don't want setters for certain fields) then you can use constructor injection instead (or combine both).